# Show and Hide different elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've created a list, and parallel to the list items, I would have different paragraphs. (List Item One - Paragraph One, List Item Two, Paragraph Two).

```
<ul>
   <li>Link One</li>
   <li>Link Two</li>
   <li>Link Three</li>
</ul>

<p>Paragraph One</p>
<p style="display:none">Paragraph Two</p>
<p style="display:none">Paragraph Three</p>
```

When I click List Item One, I would like to display Paragraph One, and hide the rest of the paragraphs. I'm using .index() to detect which List Item is being clicked.

I've tried using the .not() but I'm not sure whether I'm writing the code correctly.

```
$("ul li" ).on("click", function() {
   var number = $(this).index();

   //Display correspondent P Styles
   $("p").eq(number).show("slow");

   //hide the rest of the p styles   
   $("p").not.($(p).index(number)).hide("slow");

});
```

JSFiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/kosherjellyfish/p7C6q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hide all `p` tags first and then open the required one by using the fetched index,

```
$("p").hide().eq(number).show("slow");
```

full code,

```
$( "ul li" ).on("click", function() {
    var number = $(this).index();
    $("p").hide().eq(number).show("slow");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/p7C6q/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**:

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector

```
$("p").eq(number).show("slow").siblings('p').hide();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7C6q/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

> You may wish to use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method here:

```
$("ul li" ).on("click", function() {
   var number = $(this).index();
   //Display correspondent P Styles
   $("p").hide();
   $("p").eq(number).toggle();
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p7C6q/3/)